# html5 mobile app data transfer from server

Tags: ajax, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am breaking my head for last 2 weeks trying to create an app that will be iOS and Android using HTML5 and jQuery Mobile. I need my app to contact a server to get data. I was trying Ajax but it can not be done because of cross domain policy. I was trying iFrame which I found clever as idea to get a solution to my problem BUT I can not get it's html content.

I am new to this mobile App development. Can anyone suggest me a solution how to get this done? What is the best practice for an app to contact to server and retrieve data from it?

I am not loading html from a server and then run my app on mobile device through mobile browser. I will have my app compiled for mobile platform (iOS and/or Android) and run it from there.
For Development I use IDE=Brackets, with "Edge Inspect" plugin which allows me to run app on device as I develop it.

Thank you!